# Confused with inserting row

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

I'm using Node.js to run a MySQL command and get an error when inserting into the datatbase

```
const db = require("../db.js")
 db.query('INSERT INTO subways (listing_id,name,distance,lines) VALUES (?,?,?,?)', [results[0]['listing_id'], closestStations[index].properties.name, distance.distance.text, closestStations[index].properties.line], function (error, subwayResults, fields) {
    if (error) console.log(error)
 })
```

And this is my error
{ Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'lines) VALUES (179,'Wall St','89 ft','2-3')' at line 1

The code seems similar to the other insert commands

Comment: [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287767/er-parse-error-on-node-mysql-when-inserting-multiple-values)

Comment: You are using a reserved mysql key word `lines` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Avoid these kind of column names or use ` ` to wrap the column name in query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your values is warpped  by single quote and also your sql string is wrapped by single quote when the values are injected  you obtain an invalid quote sequence 
try using  double quote for sql code

```
const db = require("../db.js")
 db.query("INSERT INTO subways (listing_id,name,distance,`lines`) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,?)", [results[0]['listing_id'],
         closestStations[index].properties.name, distance.distance.text, 
         closestStations[index].properties.line], function (error, subwayResults, fields) {
    if (error) console.log(error)
 })
```

Comment: That would make sense because the second error is
VALUES (182, \'Wall St\', \'89 ft\', \'2-3\',182, \'Broad St\', \'0.1 mi\', \'J-Z\',1\' at line 1'

Comment: @yosefyomtobian  .. explain better you comment  ..  don't understand

Comment: It seems like its having issues with double and single quotes when it's giving me a parse error

Comment: then show the real content for the values ..please .. i have also wrapped the word /reserved) lines  using backtics  .. answer  updated

Comment: I showed the actual content up in the questions error. but I think your correct about the quotation issue Also what would the backtics do?

Comment: then was also related to the lines  reversed  word??